# Copying structure to char* buffer

Tags: c, pointers, structure, memcpy

Basicly i have a custom structure that contains different kind of data. For example:

```
typedef struct example_structure{
uint8_t* example_1[4];
int example_2[4];
int example_3;
} example_structure;
```

What i need to do is to copy context of this structure to a `const char* buffer` so i can send that copied data (`buffer`) using winsock2's `send(SOCKET s, const char* buffer, int len, int flags)` function. I tried using `memcpy()` but wouldn't i just copy address of pointers and not the data?

Comment: _"I tried using memcpy() but wouldn't i just copy address of pointers and not the data?"_ It will copy the data. You can also use `std::copy`, respectively don't need to copy at all. A simple cast will do fine.

Comment: Hmm alright, ill give it a shot.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - It is tagged as C, not C++

Comment: @EdHeal Yes it was retagged after I wrote my comment.

Comment: You need to serialise the data for the `uint8_t *` data. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

Comment: It's kinda tricky, since the example i gave is pretty similar to a structure that i'm trying to send which is a part of FFmpeg libavformat definition. What i'm actually trying to do is to send a single decoded frame using send function to a different application running on the same machine.

Comment: "What I need to do is to copy context of this structure" -> do you mean "copy the CONTENT of this structure"?

Comment: Also, your question is explicitly "wouldn't i just copy address of pointers and not the data?", and 2 questions already answer exactly that, but then you turn around and say that that is not a problem. So, what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: Yep, i need to copy data from the structure to a char* buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you copied or sent that structure through a socket you would end up copying/sending pointers, which would obviously be meaningless to the recipient, however, if the recipient is running on different hardware (e.g. not the same endian), all of the data may be meaningless anyway. On top of that, differences in the amount of padding between structure members may also become a problem.

For non-trivial situations it is best to use an existing protocol (such as [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf)), or roll your own protocol, keeping in mind the potential differences in hardware representation of your data.

Comment: Recipient is running on the same machine, i'm just using socket programming to test sending and receiving data, and differences between time consumption using different compression methods. So for my needs i can even work with addresses because memory is local.

Comment: @SirDrinksCoffeeALot: That would work only if the recipient and sender were the same process. If the recipient and sender are different processes, sending pointers won't work because each process has its own virtual address space.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are totally right, i forgot about that. So i need to actually send raw data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to design a protocol before you can encode the data in accord with that protocol. Decide exactly how the data will be encoded at the byte level. Then write code to encode and decode to that format that you decided on.

Do not skip the step of actually documenting the wire protocol at the byte level. It will save you pain later, I promise.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35834057/721269) for a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* buffer
```

This buffer has a constant value so u cant copy anything to it. You probably don't need to copy anything. Just use `send` function in such a way:

```
send(s, (char*)&example_structure, sizeof(structure), flags)
```

But here is the problem with pointers in your structure (`uint8_t* example_1[4];`). 
Sending pointers between different applications / machine does not make sense.

Comment: That buffer is just a prototype of send function. Transferring pointers between applications is just a speed test between different compression methods in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, your struct contains `uint8_t *` fields, what looks like C strings... It does not make sense copying or sending a **pointer** which is just a mere memory address in sending process user space.

If your struct has been (note, no pointers):

```
typedef struct example_structure{
uint8_t example_1[4];
int example_2[4];
int example_3;
} example_structure;
```

and provided you transfer it on **exactly same architecture** (same hardware, same compiler, same compiler options), you could do simply:

```
example_structure ex_struc;
// initialize the struct
...
send(s, &ex_struc, sizeof(ex_struc), flags);
```

And even in that case, I would strongly advise you to define and use a protocol - as already said by @DavidSchwartz, it could save you time and headaches later...

But as you have pointers, you cannot do that and **must** define a protocol.

it could be (but you are free to prefere little endian order, or 2 or 8 bytes for each int depending on your actual data):

- one byte (or two) for length of first `uint8_t` array, followed by the array
- above repeated 3 more times
- four bytes in big endian order for first int of example_2
- repeated 3 times
- four bytes in big endian order for int of example_3

This clearly defines the format of a message.